# How to add image field to custom content type?

Tags: 7, entities

I am new to Drupal and I was trying to create a custom content type via programming. I have used the following code:

```
$content_type = node_type_set_defaults($slideshow_images);
node_add_body_field($content_type, $t('Body'));
node_type_save($content_type);
```

to achieve the title and body of the content type. How can I add an image field to this?